# how to cancel timeout inside a function

Tags: javascript

how to cancel timeout inside a function

this what I have tried

set timeout to variable then clear it

please advise if I'm doing something wrong here

```
var timer1 = null;
var timer2 = null;



function pointsLoop() {

    for (let i = 0; i <= pointsList.length; i++) {
        let point = pointsList[i]
        timer1 = setTimeout(function timer() {
            point.click()
            point.classList.add("active");
        }, i * 3000);

        timer2 = setTimeout(function timer() {
            point.classList.remove("active");
            if (i == pointsList.length) {
                i = 0
            }
        }, (i * 3000) + 3000);
    }
}



$(".savemomery").click(
    function () {
        clearTimeout(timer1);
        clearTimeout(timer2);
    }

);
```

Comment: Note that you're creating a lot of timers, but only save one id (the last one)…

Comment: your question is incomplete, => https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: To be more clear, the only timeouts you clear are for `pointsList[pointsList.length - 1]`

Comment: @MikeS.
so how can I do it in the right way

Comment: @deceze how can I do it in the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store all timeouts in a array, then cancel them all at once by looping this array.

Something like :

```
let timeoutsArray = [];


function pointsLoop() {

    for (let i = 0; i <= pointsList.length; i++) {
        let point = pointsList[i]

        timeoutsArray.push( setTimeout(function timer() {
            point.click()
            point.classList.add("active");
        }, i * 3000));

        timeoutsArray.push( setTimeout(function timer() {
            point.classList.remove("active");
            if (i == pointsList.length) {
                i = 0
            }
        }, (i * 3000) + 3000));
    }
}

$(".savemomery").click(function() {
    for(let timeout of timeoutsArray) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    timeoutsArray = [];
});
```